# On GCP Docker image pulling got an error: Untar error on re-exec cmd: fork/exec /proc/self/exe: stale NFS file handle

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

In Console of Google Cloud Platform I try to pull and setup a Docker image:
`sudo docker pull nginx:1.10.0` but falling into an error:

`~$ sudo docker pull nginx:1.10.0
1.10.0: Pulling from library/nginx
51f5c6a04d83: Extracting [==================================================>] 51.36 MB/51.36 MB
a3ed95caeb02: Download complete
14ef99dba46e: Download complete
3e91b3ec524a: Download complete
FATA[0002] failed to register layer: Untar error on re-exec cmd: fork/exec /proc/self/exe: stale NFS file handle`

Is an anybody experienced same issue?

Comment: Are you on Linux?

Comment: Yes this is Ubuntu installed in first lesson of that free course: https://www.udacity.com/course/scalable-microservices-with-kubernetes--ud615

Comment: The problem is that you are not running the commands in the VM. Be sure to run the commands to start the VM and then run the command to install docker and nginx. I had the same problem until I realized the commands are suppose to be run in the VM that we start a couple of slides before. Hope this Helps,
Susan Conger

Comment: Have you tried something like `service docker restart`. What have you tried? can you give more details?